# Convert the ExecuteReader in to XML HTTP Response

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have an Web API craeted which calls the stored procedure, the stored procedure insert/updates and select a record in the Database. Insert/Update works, trying to convert the selected record that is read using `ExecuteReader` in to `HTTPResponseMessage`

```
 [HttpGet]
    public  HttpResponseMessage Get(string Account)
    {
      if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Account))
        {
          return Request.CreateResponse(new { error = "Input parameters cannot be Empty or NULL" });
        }
       string strcon = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBConnection"].ConnectionString;
       SqlConnection DbConnection = new SqlConnection(strcon);
       SqlDataReader reader = null;
       DbConnection.Open();

       SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("[dbo].[usp_InserUpadte]", DbConnection);
       command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

       //create type table
       DataTable table = new DataTable();
       table.Columns.Add("AccountID", typeof(string));
       table.Rows.Add(Account);

       SqlParameter parameter = command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@account_TT", table);
       parameter.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured;
       parameter.TypeName = "account_TT";

       XmlReader xreader = command.ExecuteXmlReader(); 

       List<QueryResult>qresults = new List<QueryResult>();

       while (xreader.Read())
       {
           QueryResult qr = new QueryResult();
           qr.AccountID = xreader["AccountID"].ToString();
           qr.CounterSeq = xreader["CounterSeq"].ToString();

           qresults.Add(qr);
       }
```

I am not sure how to build the Response in XML, I created a class called QueryResult but I am not sure if this can be used in create the XML Response.

```
  public class QueryResult
 {
        public string AccountID { get; set; }
        public string CounterSeq { get; set; }
 }
```

Also I am trying to write theresponse in the file when the API is executed. I havedone this with JSON and OracleDatabase earlier and not sure with this one. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to return your `qresults` object and it will be automatically serialized into XML (or JSON). You can read how to add attributes to your `QueryResult` class to get the xml structured the way you would like it here [JSON and XML Serialization in Web API](https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/json-and-xml-serialization)

I would also recommend returning a `IHttpActionResult` instead of building a `HttpResponseMessage` up. Then you can simply do this at the end of your message and it will automatically be serialized based on the http `ACCEPT` header:

```
[HttpGet]
public IHttpActionResult Get(string Account)
{
    // rest of implementation left out for readability...    
    return Ok(qresults);
}
```

Comment: Do I need to use ExecuteReader or XmlReader

Comment: You can use ExecuteReader and let web api handle the serialization.

Comment: Because when I use        XmlReader xreader = command.ExecuteXmlReader();  it throws error like Invalid command sent to ExecuteXmlReader.The command must return an XML Result

Comment: It returns the result in the JSON when run the application like [{"AccountID" :"Research","CounterSeq":"3"}]

Comment: What are you using the make the web request? You have to make sure the HTTP REQUEST is like this: `ACCEPT application/xml`

Comment: Where do I have to check the HTTP REQUEST.. I am new to Web API and not able to figure this out.

Comment: You need to verify with the *client* making the request to the web api. Alternatively you can disable JSON for your whole application if you don't plan on using JSON at all.